# $\psi_n \xrightarrow{w} 0$ when $\psi_n \in sp[\phi_1,..,\phi_n]^{\perp}$ an orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{\phi_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Suppose we let $\lambda_n = \sup_{\psi \in \operatorname{sp}[\phi_1,..,\phi_n]^{\perp},||\psi|| = 1} ||T\psi||$ for $T$ a compact operator on $H$.

We note that $\lambda_n$ is monotonically decreasing and hence converges to $\lambda \geq 0$. If we choose $\psi_n \in \operatorname{sp}[\phi_1,..,\phi_n]^{\perp}$ with $||\psi_n||=1$ s.t $||T\psi_n|| \geq \lambda/2$ how does it follow that $\psi_n \xrightarrow{w} 0$?

Using the Rietz lemma I thought of taking, for every $l \in H^*, y\in H$ with $(y,x) = l(x)$. Then $l(\psi_n) = (\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}a_m\phi_m,\psi
_n)$. Can I bound this somehow?

Comment: I don't understand: if all $\psi_n$ satisfy $||\psi_n||=1$, it is impossible that $\psi_n\to 0$...

Comment: Something is wrong: Firstly, your $\lambda_n$ are increasing, and in fact converging to $\|T\|$. Secondly, if $\psi_n\xrightarrow{w} 0$, then $\|T\psi_n\|\to 0$ since $T$ is compact.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Corrected

Comment: @Mariah my doubts still stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\psi_n\in \operatorname{sp}[\phi_1,...,\phi_n]^\perp$, we write $\psi_n=\sum_{i=n+1}^{+\infty} c_i^n\phi_i$ with $1=||\psi_n||= (\sum_{i=n+1}^{+\infty} (c_i^n)^2)^{1/2}$.

For all $u=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} a_i\phi_i\in H$ we have:

$|(\psi_n,u)|=\left|\sum_{i=n+1}^{+\infty}c_i^na_i\right|\le(\sum_{i=n+1}^{+\infty}(c_i^n)^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{i=n+1}^{+\infty}(a_i)^2)^{1/2}=(\sum_{i=n+1}^{+\infty}(a_i)^2)^{1/2}=(||u||^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i)^2)^{1/2}\longrightarrow0 \qquad n\to\infty.$

As you wrote, by Riesz representation theorem, we conclude that $l(\psi_n)\to0$ for all $l\in H^*$, that is $\psi_n$ weakly converges to $0$.